# How to pass information using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

First of all sorry for asking about something as basic as this but I can't make this code work because I lack knowledge about pointers.

Let's start, I've got this structures for a game:

```
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    int theres_prize;
    int is_intersection;
    int is_wall;
}Square;

typedef struct{
    int points_to_win;
   Square sqr[14][14];  
}Board;
```

I create `Board brd;` in the main and proceed to call this function when the user wants to star playing:

```
NewGame(brd);
```

Which is this:

```
void NewGame(Board *brd){

    char map;
    printf("Default map (y/n)? ");
    scanf("%c",&map);
    if(map=='y'){
        LoadDefault(brd);
    }
}
```

In `LoadDefault` I need to fill `brd` with the information of every square in the game. I will use this information throughout all the game, that's why I create the variable `brd` in the main because I need to pass it to other functions I will create there. (and that's why I need to use pointers too)

```
void LoadDefault(Board *brd){
    brd.sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1;
    printf(brd.sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1);
}
```

Tried to printf some info in `LoadDefault` to see if it worked but it isn't, for pointer problems. I would like to know how to properly pass `brd` through those functions so once I fill it in LoadDefault I can use it in the main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a syntax problem.  Since brd is a pointer, you have to dereference it to get to sqr:

```
void LoadDefault(Board *brd){
    brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1;
    printf("%d", brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize); // edit: added format specifier string
}
```

Edit: the other error is likely due to brd being a struct rather than a pointer to a struct, where you're calling NewGame.  You probably just need to pass the address, rather than the struct itself:

```
NewGame(&brd);
```

Hang in there, you'll get it!  Here's a pretty good, concise article that might help, including a link to a video:

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/

Comment: I tried it but still having several errors. In the header for the declaration of `void NewGame(Board *brd);` theres this error: **expected 'struct Board*' but argument is of type 'Board'**. When I call it theres this error: **incompatible type for argument 1 of 'NewGame'**.  Also when trying to print `brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize` theres this error: **passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**

Comment: I will edit the answer to get rid of argument 1 of 'printf' error - printf's first argument is a pointer to string.  The other error is likely due to the need to pass the address of `brd`, if brd is not already a pointer.  I will add what I suspect there in the edited answer as well.

Comment: Yeah! The printf inside `LoadDefault` it's working! it prints a 1 as it should. But I tried to printf the same information in the main like this `printf("\n\n%d" ,brd.sqr[10][10].theres_prize);` but it prints a 4...

Comment: I managed to solve it at last! I wrote an answer, thx a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
 void LoadDefault(Board *brd){
     brd.sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1;
     printf(brd.sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1);
  }
```

in this function since brd is a pointer then you need to change your code like this

```
 void LoadDefault(Board *brd){
           brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1;
           printf(brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1);
         }
```

Comment: I tried it but still having several errors. In the header for the declaration of `void NewGame(Board *brd);` theres this error: **expected 'struct Board*' but argument is of type 'Board'**. When I call it theres this error: **incompatible type for argument 1 of 'NewGame'**.  Also when trying to print `brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize` theres this error: **passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**

Comment: the problem is that in the declaration you declare `Board brd` when you should declare it `Board *brd`also in `printf`you are missing some arguments you should write `brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1 ; printf("%d",brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve the problem with the pointers thx to Timothy Jhons, some searchings about pointers and trial/error. Here's the code:

In the main.c I call this:

```
NewGame(&brd);//sending where the memory adress of my variable is
```

Then

```
void NewGame(Board *brd){
    char map;
    printf("Default map (y/n)? ");
    scanf("%c",&map);
    if(map=='y'){
        LoadDefault(brd);//I send &(*brd) which is the same as brd
    }
}

void LoadDefault(Board *brd){
    brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize=1;//which Is the same as (*brd).sqr[10][10]...
    printf("%d",brd->sqr[10][10].theres_prize);//this prints 1 as it should
}
```

And also I tried to print the same info but in the main and it prints 1, so it's working.

```
//after the call to NewGame
printf("%d", brd.sqr[10][10].theres_prize);//It prints 1 as it should :D
```